# php dropdown with another form and submit

Tags: php, html, drop-down-menu

Hey this problem may look really easy to solve but i can't find any solution, my dropdown isn't saving

```
<?php
   // the relative path to the file
   $fname = "Erros1.txt";
   $fname2 = "Comentarios.txt";
   // read in the file if present
   if(file_exists($fname)) $txt = file_get_contents($fname);
   if(file_exists($fname2)) $Comentarios = file_get_contents($fname2);    

   // if the user pushes the submit button
   if(isset($_POST["Comentarios"])){
       $Comentarios = $_POST["Comentarios"];   // get the entered content    
       file_put_contents($fname2,$Comentarios);    // write the content to the file
   }

   if (isset($_POST["dropdown"])) {
       // cast to integer to avoid malicious values
       $dropdown = (int)$_POST["dropdown"];
   }

?>

<form method="post" action="#">
<textarea name = "txt" cols = "120" rows = "20">
<?php echo $txt; ?>
</textarea>

<textarea name = "Comentarios" cols = "120" rows = "10">
<?php echo $Comentarios; ?>
</textarea>

// here is the dropdown
<select name="dropdown";>   
<?php
    for ($x=1; $x<=4; $x++) {
        echo '<option value="' . $x . '">' . $x . '</option>' . PHP_EOL;   
    }
    echo $_POST['dropdown']
?>
</select>

<input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Only my Comentarios Box is saving, maybe i need to change the submit or create another form

Comment: Where is the `saving` code which is supposed to save `dropdown`? That code above does not save dropdown's value by design

Comment: If by “saving” you mean written to a file – well, you are only doing that for the textarea value, not for the data you are getting from the select …

Comment: so i need to save it to the file too ?

Comment: If you want it saved to the file, yes.  But as your code currently stands, all you do is cast the dropdown value to an integer and then do nothing with it.  Why would you expect it to be saved?

Comment: how do i save it them ?

Comment: How did you do it for the comments …?